# "Execute Array" problem from Database PHP

Tags: php, pdo

As I'm a beginner, I have a problem with executing an array from the database.

My code:

```
    $operation_id = (int)$_GET["operation"];
$operation_query = $db_link->prepare('SELECT * FROM `shop_users_accounting` WHERE `id` = ? AND `active` = 0 AND `user_id` = ?;');
$operation_query->execute( array($operation_id, $user_id) );
$operation = $operation_query->fetch();
if($operation == false)
{
    $answer = array();
    $answer["result"] = false;
    $answer["code"] = 2;
    exit(json_encode($answer));
}
```

For now, I can echo `$operation_id` and `$user_id` without any problem

but in `shop_users_accounting` table I have more columns, like `pay_orders` and `amount`

I have tried do like this `$operation_query->execute( array($operation_id, $user_id, $pay_orders) );` but then IF function get executed and I get false

I have tried `` $operation_query = $db_link->prepare('SELECT * FROM `shop_users_accounting` WHERE `id` = ? AND `active` = 0 AND `user_id` = ? AND `pay_orders` = ?;'); `` and the result is the same, IF function get executed and I get false

The question is, what I'm doing wrong, and how I can get `pay_orders` and `amount` from DB without getting False

Comment: are you sure `$pay_orders` is defined? not null?

Comment: You are not binding the parameters, you do that with `bind-param`, since execute takes no parameters. Take a look at the example [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: @Ant its probably `PDO` not `mysqli`

Comment: @KsaR that's what happens when you don't add tags correctly...  @Edijs What does `$db_link->errorInfo()` say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I'd define the connection adding the request to return the error from mysql:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=mydbname', $db_user, $db_pass, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
```

You see the last array()? It tells mysql to return the errors.
Then I'd put everything in a try catch block so that I can handle the errors:

```
try{
    $operation_query = $db_link->prepare('SELECT * FROM `shop_users_accounting` WHERE `id` = ? AND `active` = 0 AND `user_id` = ?;');
    $operation_query->execute( array($operation_id, $user_id) );
    $operation = $operation_query->fetch();
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

So the try block will be always executed. The catch one will be executed only if there is an error and will just echo the error message. What you will do is to put inside the catch block your logic if the query fails, after the catch block your logic if your query is successfull.

The error you are getting is obscure with your code but is probably due to a value that you pass incorrectly to the query (value of the array element). There is no strict error on the syntax you use to pass the array to the query (what you call execute the array).
I'd also suggest to use named parameters in the query and bindParams() to have a more readible code with many parameters. See [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) for more details on how to build prepared statements.